# Simple CSS transition - nothing working

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I am working on an image with a gradient that disappears on hover. However, I can't get this to transition. I've tried every webkit transition that I know of and it doesn't seem to want to work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="http://calvarygigharbor.com/heavenly-hitters/">
<div class="tinted-image"> </div></a>
```

With this CSS:

```
.tinted-image {
 -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
transition: all .7s ease;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
border-radius: 10px;

background:  
linear-gradient(
  rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  rgba(237,240,0,0.6)
),
/* image */
url(http://calvarygigharbor.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/church-softball-2018.jpg);
background-size: contain;
}

.tinted-image:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
transition: all .7s ease;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
border-radius: 10px;
background: 

/* image */
url(http://calvarygigharbor.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/church-softball-2018.jpg);
background-size: contain;
}
```

The picture and hover work beautifully minus the transition. How would you get a transition to work with this?

URL: http://calvarygigharbor.com/css-testing/

Comment: You are not overriding the linear-gradient property in your hover class. Try replacing the whole `background...` line with just this: `background-color: transparent;` Also, you don't need to copy the styles from your original `.tinted-image` class because they will be already be inherited in the hover class. I hope this clarifies things. Let me know if it doesn't, and I can try to explain in a different way.

Comment: @MForMarlon using background-color will not work because gradient is not a color but and image ... and even you define another gradient with transparent color it won't work also because we cannot have transtion on gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply transition on gradient, you may try to add transition on `background-size`. Use different value of `background-size` to adjust the way the transtion will work and you can also change the `background-position`:

```css
.tinted-image {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(237, 240, 0, 0.6)),
  /* image */
  url(http://calvarygigharbor.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/church-softball-2018.jpg);
  background-size:100% 100%, contain;
  background-position:center,center; /*OR [left,center] OR [top,center] ...*/ 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.tinted-image:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  transition: all .7s ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-size:0 0,contain; /* OR [100% 0,contain] OR [0 100%,contain] */
}
```

```html
<a href="http://calvarygigharbor.com/heavenly-hitters/">
  <div class="tinted-image"> </div>
</a>
```